# Is there a way to get dates with custom formats in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In Oracle, you can use:

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm') FROM dual;
```

to show just the year and month portion of a date. Additionally, you can set [`NLS_DATE_FORMAT`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm) to change the way dates are returned by default.

I know in SQL Server you have a [set of predefined options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) you can use:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 110) –- mm-dd-yyyy
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 111) –- yyyy/mm/dd
```

But is there an option that gives me the same freedom as Oracle's `to_char`? Preferably one that doesn't require me to create a custom function.

Comment: There is a lot of wisdom to letting your db worry about data. Data does not include formatting - that is an app-tier concern. Meaning; the db is simply not the best place to do this.

Comment: @MarcGravell I am working with a SQL script, there is no application tier.

Comment: @MarcGravell I used to think so, too. Then I had a need to return an XML document from my SQL Server function, at which point formatting dates according to the external specs for XML representation became a pure server-side task.

Comment: Up to SQL Server 2008 R2: you need to use a SQL-CLR function/procedure. With SQL Server **2012**, there will be a `FORMAT` function provided in T-SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the best option is to have a [CLR function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) that is a wrapper to .NET's [`DateTime.ToString(string format)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx).

If you don't want a separate function, you can build the required string from pieces:

```
YEAR(@d) + '-' + MONTH(@d) + '-' + DAY(@d)
```

As for the definite solution, there will be [a formatting function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx) in the next version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what version of SQL Server you are using.

**SQL Server 2005, 2008, and 2008 R2**

For these versions you would need to make use of SQLCLR to expose that functionality from .NET. You can either write your own SQLCLR function using the DateTime class (as noted in @GSerg's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8202263/577765)), or you can simply download and install the Free version of [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com/) (which I am the author of, but the **Date_Format** function is free).

Example:

```sql
SELECT SQL#.Date_Format(GETDATE(), 'dddd in MMMM', '') AS [Default_language],
       SQL#.Date_Format(GETDATE(), 'dddd in MMMM', 'he') AS [Hebrew],
       SQL#.Date_Format(GETDATE(), 'dddd in MMMM', 'de') AS [German];
```

Returns:

```
Default_language      Hebrew               German
Monday in January     יום שני in ינואר    Montag in Januar
```

**SQL Server 2012 and newer**

Use the built-in [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function.

Example:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dddd in MMMM') AS [Default_language],
       FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dddd in MMMM', 'he') AS [Hebrew],
       FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dddd in MMMM', 'de') AS [German];
```

Returns:

```
Default_language      Hebrew               German
Monday in January     יום שני in ינואר    Montag in Januar
```

**For both SQLCLR and built-in `FORMAT` options**

The following two MSDN pages detail the available formatting options:

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)
- [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)