# SQL PM AM Result

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have small table

```
Create Table TestDates
(
  TestDateId int identity (1,1),
  RunDateTime DateTime
)
```

See below the data

```
Insert into TestDates
(RunDateTime)
Values
(getdate())

Insert into TestDates
(RunDateTime)
Values
( DATEADD(DAY,  -1, GETDATE()))

Insert into TestDates
(RunDateTime)
Values
( DATEADD(DAY,  -2, GETDATE()))

Insert into TestDates
(RunDateTime)
Values
( DATEADD(DAY,  -3, GETDATE()))

Insert into TestDates
(RunDateTime)
Values
( DATEADD(Hour,  -34, GETDATE()))

Insert into TestDates
(RunDateTime)
Values
( DATEADD(Hour,  -12, GETDATE()))
```

I manage to execute distinct query that brings only time

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
DATENAME(hour, RunDateTime) + ':' + 
DATENAME(mi, RunDateTime) AS  DistinctDate
from TestDates
```

But I need to indicate times with PM/AM .

See in desired output

```
Current Output     Desired Output

10:33                **10:33 AM**
20:31                **08:31 PM** 
8:33                 **08:33 AM**
```

Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct substring(convert(varchar(20),RunDateTime, 9), 13, 5) +' '
+ substring(convert(varchar(30),RunDateTime, 9), 25, 2) from
TestDates;
```

Tested. Gives you the following results

1:21 AM

11:21 AM

11:21 PM

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure you want to do formatting on the server side, then consider using a formatting function. See [Is there a way to get dates with custom formats in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202257/is-there-a-way-to-get-dates-with-custom-formats-in-sql-server).

Or, you can try

```
right(convert(varchar, RunDateTime, 100), 7)
```

Edit:

```
select distinct right(convert(varchar, RunDateTime, 100), 7)
from TestDates
```

Comment: Could you post all query with the desired result

Comment: @GregoryNozik Are you kidding? Oh wait, you've got so much listed in your [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/940340/gregory-nozik). Probably you are not kidding. See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, RunDateTime, 100), 13, 2) + ':'
+ SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, RunDateTime, 100), 16, 2) + ' '
+ SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, RunDateTime, 100), 18, 2) AS DistinctDate
from TestDates
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on SQL 2008 you can do this:

```
select convert(nvarchar, cast(RunDateTime as time), 100) from TestDates
```

Here's the output for that:

```
9:31AM
9:31AM
9:31AM
9:31AM
11:31PM
9:31PM
```

Answer (score 0):

This query gets you the AM / PM part :

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CONVERT(CHAR(26), getdate(),109)),1,2))
```

Comment: Could you post all query with the desired result