# Similar function in SQL Server to string.format in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

In C#, if I do:

```
string code = string.format("C{0:000}", 7);
```

The result will be: `C007`

Is there a function in SQL Server that does the same thing? Or do I have to create a function myself?

Comment: why not do formatting on c# side

Comment: If you're looking for an exact match, a [CLR UDF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) may be the way to go.

Comment: TIme to update. Not in SQL 2005, but 2014 has a format function EXTREMELY similar to C#.

Comment: SQL Server **2012** and newer have a `FORMAT` function .....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get dates with custom formats in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202257/is-there-a-way-to-get-dates-with-custom-formats-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Clive : you might get a better / more accurate answer if you are more explicit about what you do and do not need to do regarding formatting. Do you only want to left-pad? If so, that is answered below. If there are other format specifiers you plan on using, you need to mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [REPLICATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx), combined with [RIGHT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx)

```
'C' + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', <Padding Amount Here>) + CAST(7 AS NVARCHAR(10)), <Padding Amount Here>)
```

Usage:

```
'C' + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 10) + CAST(7 AS NVARCHAR(10)), 10)
```

Produces the follow:

> C0000000007

Comment: Added length + switched to NVARCHAR

Answer (score 5):

Use FORMATMESSAGE() function.

```
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('This is the %s and this is the %s.', 'first variable', 'second variable') AS Result;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186788.aspx

Answer (score 3):

In straight TSQL, there is nothing as powerful as the C# string.format.   The CONVERT() function offers some limited formatting, but for anything it can't handle you'd have to write your own function.   Google "SQL String functions" to see what tools you have in your SQL arsenal.

Comment: Or, don't perform this formatting in the database in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT 'C' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(3),7),3)`